# Scanner does not scan some letters in textfile

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader, filereader

I have problem with scanner to scan my textfile. When I have used this code, my output look like that. Text is in czech language and some of the letters are not recognized. Any idea where could be the problem ?

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

         File file = new File("C:/Users/Trend0226/" 
                        + "Documents/NetBeansProjects/ScreensTransition/"
                        + "src/guessword_text/Uvod_text.txt");


         Scanner sc = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)));

         while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
         String text = sc.nextLine();
             System.out.println(text);
         }

         sc.close();
}
```

Output:

```
    V�tejte ve h�e GuessWord
```

***********************  �vod  ***********************

C�lem hry je uhodnout slovo. Kdy� hr�� uhodne
 slovo z�sk�v� 1000 K�. Nejvy��� ��stku, kterou
 m��e hr�� vyhr�t je 10 000 K�. K dispozici jsou
 3 n�pov�dy, kter� hr�� m��e vyu��t. Zda-li hr�� 
 neuhodne prvn� slovo, t�m pro n�go hra skon�ila.
 Hr�� m� kdykoliv pr�vo ukon�it hru a odn�st si 
 svoji odm�nu.

********************  Upozorn�n�  ********************

Hr�� mus� b�t star�� 18-ti let, jinak se nem��e 
 z��astnit t�to hry

Answer (score 1):

Use the overloaded constructor with a charset:

`Scanner sc = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)), "UTF-8");`

Comment: please be aware that the encoding might not be UTF-8, then use the good one

Comment: Yes, I used UTF-8 because it's a good catch-all able to capture a lot of characters overlapping with other specific encodings.

Comment: When I put UTF-8 in the code, the IDe does not accept it.

Comment: What does the IDE say? Make sure you pass it to the Scanner constructor, not the FileReader or BufferedReader constructor.

Comment: I did it like in your example and it has written me, that no suitable contructor found for Scanner

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(file, "Windows-1250");
```

FileReader is an old utility class that uses the default platform encoding. Not portable, for local files only. One also could use InputStreamReader instead.

And Czech on Windows uses code page 1250, I think.